# SonarQube get property in RulesDefinition

Tags: java, properties, sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I'm trying to access a `Property` in the class extending `RulesDefinition` of my SonarQube plugin.
I define that Property in the class extending `SonarPlugin` with:

```
@Properties(
    @Property(key="sonar.root.path", name="Path to installation", description = "Root directory of the Master plugin installation directory")
)
```

the Property is properly created and I set it's value in SQ's configuration page, but somehow I can't access it from the class extending `RulesDefinition` with this code in the overridden `define(Context context)` method:

```
// Get access to the Properties
Settings settings = new Settings(new PropertyDefinitions(new MyPlugin()));
if(settings.hasKey("sonar.root.path")) {
    // Never enters here
    String path = settings.getString("sonar.root.path");
} else {
    // If always returns false and enters here
    LOG.info("No property defined with the provided key.");
}

// To double-check
LOG.info("The value: " + settings.getString("sonar.root.path"));   // Returns null

LOG.info("Has default value: " + settings.hasDefaultValue("sonar.root.path"));    
// Returns false, or true if I provide a default value, proving it can
    // access the property - so the if condition above should have returned true
```

The strange thing is that I've checked the Property via the REST Web Service and can confirm that the values shown are the ones set in the web page, but if I provide a default value (like stated just above) the log shows the default value and not the value entered in the web page (and shown via the Web Service).

Maybe the problem is in the way I get the `Settings` object. Would appreciate any help provided.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The component Settings is instantiated by core and must be injected in your object through a constructor parameter:

```
public class YourRulesDefinition implements RulesDefinition {
  private final Settings settings;

  public YourRulesDefinition(Settings s) {
    this.settings = s;
  }

  void yourMethod() {
    if(settings.hasKey("sonar.root.path")) {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Note that you should never instantiated core classes. They are always available via constructor injection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try it tomorrow and I'll provide feedback. I didn't have a constructor in this class because I didn't need to. If I create it like you suggest, the SonarQube's engine will automatically access it with instantiated information, is that so? Also, should I keep the `Property`definition in the class extending `SonarPlugin`? Thank you.

Comment: yes and yes (but [PropertyDefinition](http://javadocs.sonarsource.org/5.6/apidocs/index.html?org/sonar/api/config/PropertyDefinition.html) is preferred)